# How to setup Master to Master Replication with Application auto failover

Tags: mysql-5.5, mysql-5.6

I have a requirement as follows , need to setup a Multi-Master replication with automatic application failover ,if one master goes down, Can anyone share me some information regarding this.

Thanks and Regards
Jabir Baig Mirza

Answer (score 2):

Generally Im not a fan of Multi-Master. Since native MySQL multi-master setup will not handle the conflict detection. Im not sure about your workload, but from my personal experience, a single MySQL master can handle 30k-50k QPS. If you stick with Multi-Master think about [Percona XtraDB Cluster](https://www.percona.com/software/mysql-database/percona-xtradb-cluster) or MySQL [Group Replication](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-replication.html).

In your case, you need a load balancer on top of mysql nodes to server the traffic without downtime.

### Setup Basic Multi-Master:

There are so many articles on the internet to setup Multi-Master. I request you to use enable primary key on all tables(Innodb works better with PK). Use auto increment is ODD for Master 1, and Even identity Numbers for Master2.

> [NOTE: if you have more than 2 masters, then ignore this part, it
> won't work out. Its a simple to avoid conflict detections(Not all the
> time)]

### [ProxySQL](https://proxysql.com/):

This is my favorite option, This will work as a Load balancer and so many features. Put both masters in the same host group. So proxysql will balance the traffic to both the servers.

### [HA Proxy](http://www.haproxy.org/):

I didn't use this before, but this will act as a normal load balancer. It won't any magic like ProxySQL.

### Network Load balancer[If you are in Cloud]:

If you are using AWS, GCP or azure, they have inhouse load balancers. We can use them as well.

Comment: Thanks for your reply will look into it , can we do this application failover manually also.